# JSON Parsing C# model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I cannot seem to parse through some json to get it to a model.

The JSON:

```
{
    "status":"ok",
    "count":100,
    "data":[
        {"nickname":"God","id":null,"account_id":1000076613},
        {"nickname":"god0","id":null,"account_id":1005460397},
        {"nickname":"god1father","id":null,"account_id":1002495621},
        {"nickname":"God1Hand","id":null,"account_id":1003183995}]
}
```

My model:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public List<User> Users;
}

public class User
{

    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public string Nickname { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

}
```

My Class:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var task = await client.GetAsync(APIWebAddress);
var jsonstring = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
if (jsonstring == null) return null;
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
UserModel model = serializer.Deserialize<UserModel>(jsonstring);
```

**The problem I am having is with the serializer. It does not return the model correctly causing me to get a null reference exception later when I try to look at the data. I have tried using the JavaScriptSerializer and the Json.Net deserializer.**

Comment: Your data model doesn't contain a type for the `status` and `count`, though you might not care about those. Either way, the list containing the users is called `data` yet in your model it's called `Users`. Try changing that?

Comment: Your fourth line returns a null if `jsonstring` is null.  Are you certain that that `jsonstring` is not null at that point?  If it were, it wouldn't matter which serializer you used because it would never get there.

Comment: Also, you have `AccountId` instead of `account_id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this

**Model** (generate with [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/))

```
public class User
{
    public string nickname { get; set; }
    public object id { get; set; }
    public int account_id { get; set; } // you cant change the name*
}

public class Users
{
    public string status { get; set; } // you cant skip this
    public int count { get; set; } // you cant skip this
    public List<User> data { get; set; }
}
```

**Serializer**

Here we are using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

```
Users users =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users>(json);
```

[DEMO on DotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EfjD7Q)

*You can rename it with an attribute

Comment: Just to add some extra to this, you can get these classes using Visual Studio using the JSON in the question. Open a `cs` file, `Edit` menu, `Paste Special` and then `Paste JSON as Classes`. Very handy!

Comment: @DavidG Love it too ! You need web essentials to unlock it btw.

Comment: Seems to be working, now I am having issues passing the actual data via a RedirectToAction passing the variable.

Comment: @electrometro ask in another question, but search by yourself first. There is a lot of resource on google.

Comment: Been searching for quite awhile actually. Just didn't know what keywords to use for the class creation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code lies here:

```
UserModel model = serializer.Deserialize<UserModel>(jsonstring);
```

change it as below :

```
UserModel model = serializer.Deserialize<UserModel>(jsonstring.Result.ToString());
```

hope this helps you