# How to fix JSON with \"?

Tags: c#, json, api

I'm making an app that uses Reddit's API to get posts from sub reddits

but every time the JSON I got had \" instead of "

I tried three different methods to download the JSON from Reddit's website, but every time it's filled with \" and my deserializer can' handle that

```
var json = get_json("https://www.reddit.com/r/" + "memes" + "/new.json?sort=new&limit=1");

                string webData = json.Replace('\"', '"');

                MessageBox.Show(webData, "");

                NormalInput normal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NormalInput>(webData);
```

```
public string get_json(string url)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();

            return output;
        }
```

I expect the output from the json.Replace() or get_json() to not have any \", but I'm getting them everywhere

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just the escaped string representation in the Visual Studio Debugger?

Comment: Please add a screenshot (yes an actual picture, not copied text - I know e don't ask for them often here :) ) so we can literally see what you're seeing when you say "getting them everywhere"

Comment: The URL https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/new.json?sort=new&limit=1 returns no `\"`, only `"`, just click the link to try and see it in your browser.

Comment: yes, the url does not have any \", but my app still got them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a complete working example using dynamic and a basic WebClient:

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/noBbxk)

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        var url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/" + "memes" + "/new.json?sort=new&limit=1";
        var json =  client.DownloadString(url);
        dynamic output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(output.data.children[0].data.title);
    }
}
```

current output:

```
This meme is not dead!
```

To interact reddit, maybe you should rely on a C# reddit client library. Check [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=reddit).

If you want to keep going with an homemade solution (for fun and learning), you can improve this quick answer by using `HttpClient` instead of the old (but simple) `WebClient` and switch from the dynamic usage of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to a real class (I wrote an [answer to achieve that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761693/json-parsing-c-sharp-model/27761744#27761744). Try it ^^). If your class `NormalInput` matches the json, keep using it.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you try to download JSON from an URI. Using NewtonSoft is a good way to get json from URI.

Please take a look of this post : https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/397574/Use-Csharp-to-get-JSON-Data-from-the-Web-and-Map-i

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is from NewtonSoft. OP is aware of Json.NET :)